# Changing links color from textbox value and then store with cookies

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm bulding a Google Chrome extension and I have to change links color from a texfield and save the change with a cookie using jquery cookie plugin. This is what i'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.linkbox').append('-&nbsp;<a class="save" href="#">&nbsp-;save</a><input id="textbox" name="textbox" value="" />');

$('#textbox').keypress(function(event) {
     if (event.which == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
     $(".linkstochange").filter('a[href$="'+$(this).val()+'"]').addClass("green");
     $.cookie("linkstosave", "green", {path: '/'});
   }
});

var rememberme = $.cookie("linkstosave");
    if (rememberme == "green") {
        $(".linkstochange").filter('a[href$="'+$(this).val()+'"]').addClass("green");
};
});
```

Html

```
<div class = "linkstochange">
<a href = "u123">firstlink</a>, <a href ="u333">secondlink</a>, <a href="u656">thirdlink</a>, <a href="u656">thirdlink</a>...
</div>
```

The problem is that if i click on the link "Save" all the links change color (not only one) and then if i refresh tha page nothing is saved. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with the cookies (what do you want to save: links or class?) but this code might help you out:

http://jsbin.com/atisaf/31

Comment: What i would like to save is that when i write (for example) u333 the link change color (green) and when I refresh the page the link is green (sorry for my English)